# How do I find the mappings between sedol and isin codes?

Tags: online-data-source, market-data

I am looking at data for Unit Trusts and OEICs in the UK.

They are identified by SEDOL or ISIN codes.

Given an SEDOL, how can I find the ISIN associated with the same product?  And given an ISIN, how can I find the associated SEDOL?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: For the purpose of matching data between different data sources.

Comment: You can use the tool on ISINdb.com: [Convert SEDOL to ISIN](https://www.isindb.com/convert-sedol-to-isin/)

Answer (score 3):

There is a relatively straightforward transformation explained on the Wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identifying_Number) and on the links from that page.  Note that this only applies to SEDOLs for instruments listed on the London Stock Exchange (LSE).

To convert SEDOL to ISIN you pad leading zeroes onto the SEDOL until you have 9 digits.  Then you add the two letter country code (as defined in [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)) to the front.  Then you add a final checksum digit to the end, again as defined in the algorithm on the Wikipedia page.

To convert ISIN to SEDOL you do the reverse: remove the final digit, remove the two leading letters, and strip off any leading zeroes.

Example:

- RIOl - SEDOL: 0718875 -> ISIN: GB0007188757

Comment: It doesn't work as neatly as that in practice as you can have multiple SEDOLS for one ISIN for different currencies.  E.g. Siemens Ords, ISIN DE0007236101 has SEDOLS 5727973, 5735233 and 5727973 on the German exchange and 5751615 on the French exchange.

Comment: I stand corrected.  You are quite right about this mismatch in EU symbols.  The algorithm on Wikipedia works only for symbols listed under the aegis of the London Stock Exchange (LSE).  I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks! How did you know that?

Comment: Because I recently read those Wikipedia pages.  (But not well enough to notice the issues that @ChrisDegnen pointed out.)

Comment: Some further info here: [Unique Security Identification](http://securities.blogspot.co.uk/2005/10/reference-data-bible-fisd_22.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information through Bloomberg, but it's a paid service.

Comment: OP does not appear to be asking how to get the raw data but rather how to convert between two different identifying keys in the data.

Comment: You will need a data source like Bloomberg to pick up all the SEDOL variations.  Many of them do not follow the rule you quoted.